# Google Chrome Issues

Tags: magento2, cache, chrome-browser

[image]When adding products to a cart, viewing the cart ect. It works as expected in Firefox however in Google Chrome when click 'Add to Cart' it just takes the user to a empty cart page.

Something to do with the Google Chrome Cache?

Comment: Is there any browser console error log?

Comment: Added console log screenshot

Answer (score 0):

This is cookie issue. I have faced the same issue while i am using M2 in localhost.
To solve this I have changed the base url localhost to 127.0.0.1
If you are having the issue in localhost during development, this will solve the issue.